# Matlab - crop image based on foreground-background segmentation

Tags: matlab

I have an RGB image which is read as a matrix with 3 dimensions, `img`, and I have a binary mask which represents a  segmentation of the image, `mask`.

How can I crop the image based on the binary mask in matlab? 
I tried to select only the pixels marked by the binary mask but the resulted image does not have the original colors.

```
centralPoints = find(mask > 0);
denoisedImage = zeros(424, 424, 3);
slice1 = zeros(424, 424);
origSlice = img(:, :, 1);
slice1(centralPoints) = origSlice(centralPoints);
slice2 = zeros(424, 424);
origSlice = img(:, :, 2);
slice2(centralPoints) = origSlice(centralPoints);
slice3 = zeros(424, 424);
origSlice = img(:, :, 3);
slice3(centralPoints) = origSlice(centralPoints);

denoisedImage(:, :, 1) = slice1;
denoisedImage(:, :, 2) = slice2;
denoisedImage(:, :, 3) = slice3;
```

This is the code. `img` is the original image, `centralPoints` are the coordinates of the foreground pixels and `denoisedImage` represents the cropped matrix.

However, `denoisedImage` does no maintain the colors of the original image inside the cropped region.
The foreground pixels do not form a rectangular region, however, they form one connected component.

Comment: Is the `mask` rectangular?

Comment: No, mask is not rectangular, but it is connected, all the foreground pixels form one connected graph component.

Comment: You said `centralPoints` represents the coordinates, so is it a Nx2 matrix of X-Y coordinates?

Comment: I have added a piece  of code where I illustrate for I obtained the coordinates.

Comment: Also does `denoisedImage` has the same size as `img`?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not have the original colours" - when you use `imshow` or similar? When you write the image out?

Comment: Did you try turning your mask in a 3D array using `repmat` and use `.*` operation?

Comment: Is it possible that `img` is `uint8` while `denosedImage` is of type `double`?

Comment: It was because `denoisedImage` was `double` and `img` was `uint8`. After converting `denoisedImage` to `uint8` everything was ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
denoisedImage = bsxfun( @times, im2double(img), mask > 0 );
```

Comment: OP might need some modifications - `denoisedImage = uint8(bsxfun( @times, double(img), mask > 0 ));`

Comment: @Divakar See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610429/matlab-crop-image-based-on-foreground-background-segmentation/22610944?noredirect=1#comment34428446_22610429) asking about the used data types. Changes should be made based on OP's answer to that comment.